# FirebaseRecyclerOptions with spinner onItemSelected query issue

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, spinner, firebaseui

I have a spinner with locations and I would like to click on the location from the spinner and filter my Firebase data to show all items with that location selected.

I have tried putting the "onItemSelected" code fragment in the onStart area before and after the FirebaseRecyclerOptions and when I open the app and select the location from the spinner nothing new populates. It still shows all the data and all the locations.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    Spinner mLocationSpinner;
    DatabaseReference mRef;
    FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 2));

        mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mRef = (DatabaseReference) mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("Data");

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Model> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Model>()
                        .setQuery(mRef, Model.class)
                        .build();



        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Model, ViewHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder , int position , @NonNull Model model) {
                holder.setDetails(getApplicationContext(), model.getBusiness(), model.getImage());

                mLocationSpinner = (SearchableSpinner) findViewById(R.id.locationSpinner);
                ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> spinAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(MainActivity.this,
                        R.array.location_arrays, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                spinAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

                mLocationSpinner.setAdapter(spinAdapter);
                mLocationSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent , View view , int position , long id) {
                        String locationSpinner = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                        Query querySpinner = mRef.orderByChild("location").equalTo(String.valueOf(mLocationSpinner));


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                    }
                });
            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent , int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);

                return new ViewHolder(view);
            }
        };

        firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }
```

Comment: What's the error you get? Please edit your question to include the exact message and (if available) stack trace.

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question. Please respond with @